# Core Data child contexts not prefetching relationships

Tags: ios, core-data

I activated the Core Data debugger `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1` in my app scheme and got the following results for an entity called Category with a relationship entity called Image:

**FetchRequest on the main context:**

```
NSFetchRequest *fr = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Category"];
fr.relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching = @[@"image"];

NSArray *results = [self.mainContext executeFetchRequest:fr error:nil];

for (Category *category in results) {

    NSLog(@"%@", category.image.width);
}
```

The console log shows no faults being fulfilled - the expected behavior since the image relationship was set for prefetching.

**The same request on a child context:**

```
NSManagedObjectContext *privateMOC = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
[privateMOC setParentContext:self.mainContext];

[privateMOC performBlock:^{

        NSFetchRequest *fr = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Category"];
        fr.relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching = @[@"image"];

        NSArray *results = [privateMOC executeFetchRequest:fr error:nil];

        for (Category *category in results) {

            NSLog(@"%@",category.image.width);
        }
    }];
```

In this case, the console shows Core Data fulfilling faults for each image (4 of them). Is this a bug, expected behavior or am I missing something please?

Comment: This is why i switched to realm.io over core data!

Comment: My parent context tried to fetch transient relationships from the sqlte store. This could be the same or a similar bug.

Comment: What is the purpose of prefetching? If you do *not* prefetch you could have Core Data fetch the image automatically when you actually need it. If you are concerned about memory or persistent store performance, you probably should not store large images in the persistent store in the first place.

Comment: Could you post your log and point out the delta?

Comment: @Mundi Image is a relationship and does not contain any binary attributes.

Comment: There are plenty of various bugs in nested contexts in Core Data like this you described, or ignoring `fetchLimit`, etc. Are you sure you need to use them? They was originally designed to increase granularity in data manipulation, not for concurrency. If your aim is for concurrency – use private queue or even confinement type context, attached to its own `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`.

Comment: @RunLoop Not a private queue but nested contexts was not meant for concurrency. Idea is that you create nested context, let the user make some changes to one object and then save those changes or discard them. For large background import, for example, private MOC or confined MOC in background thread with its own PSC has much better overall performance on writes since it results only in SQLite file blocks, which is much faster than PSC locks. I'll search for WWDC sessin for you, wait a sec...

Comment: @RunLoop Oh, it's 2013, time flies fast. Starts at 25:30 https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013-211/

Comment: BTW, about Realm. In real-life application with about half-million records in DB I've got about the same performance on import with Realm as with Core Data, provided that no inverse relationships were used. That, and very poor realization of change notifications at this time, along with resource-greedy and inefficient FRC analogs in Realm… I think I'll stick with Core Data for the next couple of years.

Comment: Have to concur with @bteapot  Recently tried to integrate Realm on Android. Absolute nightmare. No relationship management. Abstract or poor queries. Other, nagging limitations. Only suitable for the most simple of db needs.

Answer (score 5):

#### Experiment:

I have replicated your scenario in a test app and come to the same conclusion: the prefetching is not happening in the background thread. Log:

```
******************************** FOREGROUND **************************************

CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZTIMESTAMP, t0.ZTITLE, t0.ZIMAGE FROM ZCATEGORY t0 
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0004s
CoreData: annotation: Bound intarray values.
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZNAME, t0.ZURL FROM ZIMAGE t0 WHERE  t0.Z_PK IN (SELECT * FROM _Z_intarray0)  
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0006s
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0010s for 4 rows.
CoreData: annotation: Prefetching with key 'image'.  Got 4 rows.
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0035s for 4 rows.

******************************** BACKGROUND **************************************

CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZTIMESTAMP, t0.ZTITLE, t0.ZIMAGE FROM ZCATEGORY t0 
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0003s
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0005s for 4 rows.
```

#### Analysis:

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSFetchRequest/relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching) of `NSFetchRequest`, it is explained that the prefetching is offered to address **specific performance challenges**. It is described as follows (my emphasis):

> Prefetching allows Core Data to obtain related objects in a single fetch (per entity), rather than incurring subsequent access to the store for each individual record as their faults are tripped. For example, given an Employee entity with a relationship to a Department entity, if you fetch all the employees then for each print out their name and the name of the department to which they belong, it may be that a fault has to be fired for each individual Department object (for more details, see Core Data Performance in Core Data Programming Guide). This can represent a significant overhead. You **could** avoid this by prefetching the department relationship in the Employee fetch...

From the wording it follows that this is *not* a *necessary* device to improve performance. This would explain why it is not implemented on a background thread: the performance issue described in the discussion seems to indicate a typical scenario involving UI updates. To my mind, this clarifies the intent of this feature.

If you are already on a background thread, this kind of performance tuning is surely less critical and the usual faulting mechanism can handle the necessary optimization adequately. The property `relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching` will thus revert to its default value, an empty array.

Comment: When down voting, state your case.

Comment: I have this same issue. Firing thousands of faults is no faster on a background thread, it is slow and takes forever compared to a single prefetch. So I don't think this can be explained as any kind of intentional optimisation.

Comment: This is not related to a background thread (i.e. private queue) it appears to be an issue with using child contexts. For example if you use a private queue context and a separate PSC, like apple do in the "Earthquakes" example then this doesn't happen.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to extend your log showing the query when an image is accessed. Because remember just because it is a fault doesn't mean it isn't in the row cache. I'm not sure if child contexts share row caches.