# Why is CoreData ignoring relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Any ideas why this isn't working, my items are always faults.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *tmpContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
tmpContext.parentContext = self.managedObjectContext;

NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Bag"];
request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = NO;
request.relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching = @[@"items"];

NSArray *bags = [tmpContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];

Bag *bag = (Bag *)[bags firstObject];
NSLog(@"%@", bag.items);
```

and I get...

```
Relationship 'items' fault on managed object (0x79e90e00)
```

And if I view the CoreData query there is no JOIN in it.

```
SELECT t0.Z_ENT, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, .... FROM ZBAG t0 WHERE t0.Z_ENT = ?
```

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34018021/3985749) might be relevant.